# How to use the Workload Command in Task Bot in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I want to prioritise the BOT run in Control Room. I have two BOTs but only one server. First BOT is already scheduled. I want to run the next BOT on priority over first BOT. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Automation Anywhere application you can choose the priority of the bot in application.
 [image]
When bot with higher priority will be run while another bot is working, working bot will be paused when it comes to "Main task" and higher priority bot will start it's work. 
Be careful of that cause h-priority bot can close application used by before working bot what might interrupt or even crash the first bot.